# I search navigation bookmarks plugin which can save bookmarks between sessions

Tags: phpstorm

I have found this
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14323-free-navigation-bookmarks
plugin for PhpStorm 2023 - it works great, but closing my IDE I lose
all bookmarked saved priorly. Are there some options to save these bookmarks (I did not find) ?

Maybe some other similar plugin which can save bookmarks between sessions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Software recommendations (including plugins) are off-topic at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

PHPStorm has it's own built-in bookmarks tool. I use them all the time.

Just select the line of code you want to bookmark then use the keyboard shortcuts `Ctrl + F11` which will bring up the keyboard to add a `Mnemonic Shortcut`.

As you can see below, in the `Favourites` window open up the `Bookmarks` dropdown and you will see your bookmarks which persist during restarts.

[image]

Bookmarks can also be added using the main menu by clicking `Navigate` > `Bookmarks` > `Add Mnemonic Bookmark`.

If you `Right Click` on the little `B` next to the row number in my example you can change the `Bookmark Description` to something more memorable as it just defaults to the line of code you bookmark on.

**Edit**:

After you click `File` > `New Project` you can select the root of your codebase by clicking on the little folder icon to pick somewhere on your disk as per below screenshot.
[image]

Once you select your codebase and click `OK` you can then click `Create`. When you then click the `Create From Existing Sources` dialog the next window will allow you to select `Attach`.

Comment: Yes, a) built-in bookmarks tool is good, but from my expierence, these bookmarks are periodically lost. I suppose after I open other project in the same IDE, or opening other project in another IDE instance(having 2 IDE instances opened in the same time). Have you ever lost your bookmarks? b) I liked how plugin I pointed works I would prefer to save bookmarks between sessions.

Comment: I've never had them disappear. I think it may be the way you are adding your projects. I have multiple projects added to the my project workspace. I can have a look at the plugin to see if there is a bug.

Comment: @PetroGromovo if you open up a `File` > `New Project` >  then select your project root directory. When you get the `Create From Existing Sources` dialog on the next window select `Attach`. This will put your projects in the same session so your bookmarks should persist during restarts. Bookmarks are global so you can't have 2x `A` or 2x `B` if you know what I mean.

Comment: when I select File > New Project I do not see “Create From Existing Sources ” dialog 
But I see next dialog : 
https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/XCcVPoGnRF2h8IdZRBnREg.png

Comment: Can you select the little folder icon in the location input to select your codebase from your disk? @PetroGromovo

Comment: I did not understand which icon do you mean ? Please give a screenshot

Comment: @PetroGromovo I've added a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean that selecting exiting projects in this way with selecting "Attach" option as you wrote before will salve my problem that saved before bookmarks would not be lost ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo that is correct for the PHPStorm built-in bookmarks yes. Unfortunately, bookmarks for the plugin that you reference are lost upon restart so won't persist through sessions.

Comment: After some tests opening 2nd project with  "Attach" option seems not a good idea for me. What for to union 2 different projects.